# Is it possible to resolve the viewengine using IOC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have a custom ViewEngine that I am using with my MVC4 web app.

I register is currently in the `Global.asax` like this:

```
ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine());
```

In my `CustomViewEngine` class I have properties of classes that are available through my IOC implementation (using CastleWindsor)

At the moment I could access the windsor resolver directly in the `CustomViewEngine` and resolve them, but what I would really like to do is have the ViewEngine resolved by windsor and get all those bits for free. Without having to do it explicitly.

Is this even possible? I would want the ViewEngine then to be resolved per WebRequest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
    public class DependencyViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
    {
        public override ViewEngineResult FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialViewName, bool useCache)
        {
            var result = base.FindPartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName, useCache);
            result.ViewEngine = // resolve view engine
            return result;
        }

        public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
        {
            var result = base.FindView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName, useCache);
            result.ViewEngine = // resolve view engine
            return result;
        }

    }
```

Then

```
    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new DependencyViewEngine());
```

EDIT:

How about implementing the dependency resolver to use your container?

```
public class CustomDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{
    public CustomDependencyResolver(IContainer container)
    {
       // ...
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        // pass resolution off to your container
    }
    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        // pass resolution off to your container
    }
}
```

Then

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
   ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
   var resolver = new CustomDependencyResolver(container);
   DependencyResolver.SetResolver(resolver);
}
```

Comment: hang on, one thing I would still have to resolve that manually though right?

Comment: @shenku Updated my answer with another possibility

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom dependecy resolver service derived from IDependencyResolver. MVC calls IDependencyResolver.GetServices method, when it resolves IViewEngine interface. And if there are no services returned by this method, MVC'll call traditional API (ViewEngines.Engines).
Also there are my be more than one services returned by this method (it's competitive multi-service model). Even though it's very rare case, it still exists.
So, just implement IViewEngine interface with your custom engine, register it in your container and use custom IDependencyResolver implementation.